# Rename tag [apache-coccoon] to [apache-cocoon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I just noticed the [[apache-coccoon]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-coccoon/info) tag is spelled incorrectly. It should be `[apache-cocoon]`. I tried to at least submit a synonym, but I don't have 5 points in it.